# Message: Object required error when querying XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
test[_nObjectives].pool[j].feedbackCorrect = 
oQuestions[j].getElementsByTagName("feedbackCorrect")[0].firstChild.data;
```

and the XML in this case contains this:

```
  <feedbackCorrect>
  </feedbackCorrect>
```

When executing that line of code the following error occurs: Message: Object required

I don't get it. The tag is there, if it is empty the error occurs and even has spaces chars it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the error because

```
oQuestions[j].getElementsByTagName("feedbackCorrect")[0]
```

is returning that tag, and the .firstChild is returning null, because it has no children...

Are you sure you dont want

```
oQuestions[j].getElementsByTagName("feedbackCorrect")[0].data
```

?

Comment: but why it is working when the xml is like this:

<feedbackCorrect>any value</feedbackCorrect>

?

Answer (score 0):

but why it is working when the xml is like this:

```
<feedbackCorrect>any value</feedbackCorrect>
```

?